# $\ell_\infty$-norm covering number of RKHS ball $\{f\in\mathcal{H}: \|f\|_\mathcal{H} \leq R\}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, packing-and-covering, kernels

For any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, let $N_\infty(\epsilon, \mathcal{H}, R)$ denote the $\epsilon$-covering number of the RKHS norm ball $\{f\in\mathcal{H}: \|f\|_\mathcal{H} \leq R\}$ with respect to the $\ell_\infty$-norm. What are some reference where I can find upperbound for $\log {N_\infty(\epsilon, \mathcal{H}, R)}$?

I am currently reading this paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.04622)) and in Lemma D.2 in page 59, they give bounds under three different conditions for eigenvalue decay of $\mathcal{H}$. But the assumption seems quite restrictive and I would like the avoid this assumption.

[image]

Here is Assumption 4.3

[image]

Here is Equation (2.3) from the paper.

[image]